# Why won't my jQuery carousel show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have put a carousel in my website, but why won't it show?

My HTML:

```
            <!--Sponsor Carousel-->
              <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                <ul id="flexiselDemo1">
                    <li><img src="img/logo-nyt.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/logo-microsoft.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/logo-ebay.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/logo-hp.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/logo-youtube.png" /></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="clearout"></div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(window).load(function() {
                        $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                            enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                            responsiveBreakpoints: {
                                portrait: {
                                    changePoint:480,
                                    visibleItems: 1
                                },
                                landscape: {
                                    changePoint:640,
                                    visibleItems: 2
                                },
                                tablet: {
                                    changePoint:768,
                                    visibleItems: 3
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
            <!--End Sponsor Carousel-->
```

My CSS :

```
        #flexiselDemo1{
        display:none;

        }

        .nbs-flexisel-container {
            position:relative;
            max-width:90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .nbs-flexisel-ul {
            position:relative;
            width:9999px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style-type:none;   
            text-align:center;  
        }

        .nbs-flexisel-inner {
            overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            background:#fcfcfc;
            background: #fcfcfc -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #eee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: #fcfcfc -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fcfcfc), color-stop(100%,#eee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: #fcfcfc -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #eee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: #fcfcfc -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #eee 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
            background: #fcfcfc -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #eee 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: #fcfcfc linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #eee 100%); /* W3C */
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius:10px;
            -moz-border-radius:50px;
            -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        }

        .nbs-flexisel-item {
            float:left;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            cursor:pointer;
            position:relative;
            line-height:0px;
        }
        .nbs-flexisel-item img {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            max-width:100px;
            max-height:45px;
        }

        /*** Navigation ***/

        .nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
        .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
            width: 22px;
            height: 22px; 
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
            left: 10px;
            background: url(../images/button-previous.png) no-repeat;
        }

        .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
            right: 5px;
            background: url(../images/button-next.png) no-repeat;
        }
```

My Jquery :

/*
             * File: jquery.flexisel.js
             * Version: 1.0.2
             * Description: Responsive carousel jQuery plugin
             * Author: 9bit Studios
             * Copyright 2012, 9bit Studios
             * http://www.9bitstudios.com
             * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
             * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
             */
            (function ($) {
                $.fn.flexisel = function(options) {

```
                var defaults = $.extend({
                    visibleItems : 5,
                    animationSpeed : 1000,
                    autoPlay : true,
                    autoPlaySpeed : 5000,
                    pauseOnHover : true,
                    setMaxWidthAndHeight : false,
                    enableResponsiveBreakpoints : true,
                    clone : true,
                    responsiveBreakpoints : {
                        portrait: { 
                            changePoint:480,
                            visibleItems: 1
                        }, 
                        landscape: { 
                            changePoint:640,
                            visibleItems: 2
                        },
                        tablet: { 
                            changePoint:768,
                            visibleItems: 3
                        }
                    }
                }, options);

                /******************************
                Private Variables
                 *******************************/

                var object = $(this);
                var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
                var itemsWidth; // Declare the global width of each item in carousel
                var canNavigate = true;
                var itemsVisible = settings.visibleItems; // Get visible items
                var totalItems = object.children().length; // Get number of elements
                var responsivePoints = [];

                /******************************
                Public Methods
                *******************************/
                var methods = {
                    init : function() {
                        return this.each(function() {
                            methods.appendHTML();
                            methods.setEventHandlers();
                            methods.initializeItems();
                        });
                    },

                    /******************************
                    Initialize Items
                    Fully initialize everything. Plugin is loaded and ready after finishing execution
                *******************************/
                    initializeItems : function() {

                        var listParent = object.parent();
                        var innerHeight = listParent.height();
                        var childSet = object.children();
                        methods.sortResponsiveObject(settings.responsiveBreakpoints);

                        var innerWidth = listParent.width(); // Set widths
                        itemsWidth = (innerWidth) / itemsVisible;
                        childSet.width(itemsWidth);        
                        if (settings.clone) {
                            childSet.last().insertBefore(childSet.first());
                            childSet.last().insertBefore(childSet.first());
                            object.css({
                                'left' : -itemsWidth
                            });
                        }

                        object.fadeIn();
                        $(window).trigger("resize"); // needed to position arrows correctly

                    },

                /******************************
                    Append HTML
                    Add additional markup needed by plugin to the DOM
                *******************************/
                    appendHTML : function() {
                        object.addClass("nbs-flexisel-ul");
                        object.wrap("<div class='nbs-flexisel-container'><div class='nbs-flexisel-inner'></div></div>");
                        object.find("li").addClass("nbs-flexisel-item");

                        var flexiselInner = object.parent(); // flexisel-inner

                        if (settings.setMaxWidthAndHeight) {
                            var baseWidth = $(".nbs-flexisel-item img").width();
                            var baseHeight = $(".nbs-flexisel-item img").height();
                            $(".nbs-flexisel-item img").css("max-width", baseWidth);
                            $(".nbs-flexisel-item img").css("max-height", baseHeight);
                        }
                        $("<div class='nbs-flexisel-nav-left'></div><div class='nbs-flexisel-nav-right'></div>").insertAfter(flexiselInner);
                        if (settings.clone) {
                            var cloneContent = object.children().clone();
                            object.append(cloneContent);
                        }
                    },
                    /******************************
                    Set Event Handlers
                Set events: click, resize, etc
                    *******************************/
                    setEventHandlers : function() {

                        var listParent = object.parent();
                        var flexiselInner = listParent.parent();
                        var childSet = object.children();
                        var leftArrow = flexiselInner.find(".nbs-flexisel-nav-left");
                        var rightArrow = flexiselInner.find(".nbs-flexisel-nav-right");

                        $(window).on("resize", function(event) {

                            methods.setResponsiveEvents();

                            var innerWidth = $(listParent).width();
                            var innerHeight = $(listParent).height();

                            itemsWidth = (innerWidth) / itemsVisible;

                            childSet.width(itemsWidth);
                            if (settings.clone) {
                                object.css({
                                    'left' : -itemsWidth                            
                                });
                            }else {
                                object.css({
                                    'left' : 0
                                });
                            }

                            // Hide the arrows if the elements are the same of the visible
                            if (!settings.clone && totalItems <= itemsVisible) {
                              leftArrow.add(rightArrow).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                            }
                            else {
                              leftArrow.add(rightArrow).css('visibility', 'visible');

                              var halfArrowHeight = (leftArrow.height()) / 2;
                              var arrowMargin = (innerHeight / 2) - halfArrowHeight;
                              leftArrow.css("top", arrowMargin + "px");
                              rightArrow.css("top", arrowMargin + "px");
                            }

                        });
                        $(leftArrow).on("click", function(event) {
                            methods.scrollLeft();
                        });
                        $(rightArrow).on("click", function(event) {
                            methods.scrollRight();
                        });
                        if (settings.pauseOnHover == true) {
                            $(".nbs-flexisel-item").on({
                                mouseenter : function() {
                                    canNavigate = false;
                                },
                                mouseleave : function() {
                                    canNavigate = true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (settings.autoPlay == true) {

                            setInterval(function() {
                                if (canNavigate == true)
                                    methods.scrollRight();
                            }, settings.autoPlaySpeed);
                        }

                    },
                    /******************************
                    Set Responsive Events
                    Set breakpoints depending on responsiveBreakpoints
                    *******************************/            

                    setResponsiveEvents: function() {
                        var contentWidth = $('html').width();

                        if(settings.enableResponsiveBreakpoints) {

                            var largestCustom = responsivePoints[responsivePoints.length-1].changePoint; // sorted array 

                            for(var i in responsivePoints) {

                                if(contentWidth >= largestCustom) { // set to default if width greater than largest custom responsiveBreakpoint 
                                    itemsVisible = settings.visibleItems;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else { // determine custom responsiveBreakpoint to use

                                    if(contentWidth < responsivePoints[i].changePoint) {
                                        itemsVisible = responsivePoints[i].visibleItems;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    /******************************
                    Sort Responsive Object
                    Gets all the settings in resposiveBreakpoints and sorts them into an array
                    *******************************/            

                    sortResponsiveObject: function(obj) {

                        var responsiveObjects = [];

                        for(var i in obj) {
                            responsiveObjects.push(obj[i]);
                        }

                        responsiveObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
                            return a.changePoint - b.changePoint;
                        });

                        responsivePoints = responsiveObjects;
                    },

                    /******************************
                    Scroll Left
                    *******************************/
                    scrollLeft : function() {
                        if (object.position().left < 0) {
                            if (canNavigate == true) {
                                canNavigate = false;

                                var listParent = object.parent();
                                var innerWidth = listParent.width();

                                itemsWidth = (innerWidth) / itemsVisible;

                                var childSet = object.children();

                                object.animate({
                                    'left' : "+=" + itemsWidth
                                }, {
                                    queue : false,
                                    duration : settings.animationSpeed,
                                    easing : "linear",
                                    complete : function() {
                                        if (settings.clone) {
                                            childSet.last().insertBefore(
                                                    childSet.first()); // Get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made)                                   
                                        }
                                        methods.adjustScroll();
                                        canNavigate = true;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    /******************************
                    Scroll Right
                    *******************************/            
                    scrollRight : function() {
                        var listParent = object.parent();
                        var innerWidth = listParent.width();

                        itemsWidth = (innerWidth) / itemsVisible;

                        var difObject = (itemsWidth - innerWidth);
                        var objPosition = (object.position().left + ((totalItems-itemsVisible)*itemsWidth)-innerWidth);    

                        if((difObject <= Math.ceil(objPosition)) && (!settings.clone)){
                            if (canNavigate == true) {
                                canNavigate = false;                    

                                object.animate({
                                    'left' : "-=" + itemsWidth
                                }, {
                                    queue : false,
                                    duration : settings.animationSpeed,
                                    easing : "linear",
                                    complete : function() {                                
                                        methods.adjustScroll();
                                        canNavigate = true;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } else if(settings.clone){
                            if (canNavigate == true) {
                                canNavigate = false;

                                var childSet = object.children();

                                object.animate({
                                    'left' : "-=" + itemsWidth
                                }, {
                                    queue : false,
                                    duration : settings.animationSpeed,
                                    easing : "linear",
                                    complete : function() {                                
                                            childSet.first().insertAfter(childSet.last()); // Get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made)                                
                                        methods.adjustScroll();
                                        canNavigate = true;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        };                
                    },
                    /******************************
                    Adjust Scroll 
                     *******************************/
                    adjustScroll : function() {
                        var listParent = object.parent();
                        var childSet = object.children();

                        var innerWidth = listParent.width();
                        itemsWidth = (innerWidth) / itemsVisible;
                        childSet.width(itemsWidth);
                        if (settings.clone) {
                            object.css({
                                'left' : -itemsWidth
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
                if (methods[options]) { // $("#element").pluginName('methodName', 'arg1', 'arg2');
                    return methods[options].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                } else if (typeof options === 'object' || !options) { // $("#element").pluginName({ option: 1, option:2 });
                    return methods.init.apply(this);
                } else {
                    $.error('Method "' + method + '" does not exist in flexisel plugin!');
                }
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there error in the console? Have you inspect the container to see if the carousel is rendered?

Comment: it works when its just the carousel, but when I put it inside of my website .... something goes wrong. I've Putted the whole css in the website-css and samestory for the html. in the html ive made links for the js and jq

Comment: There are some css errors

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4m1cs6

Comment: Do you have link of the site or jsfiddle?

Comment: Dont know if this works... mike.upxdev.com/public_html/HtmlTemplate/index.html

Comment: go to jsfiddle.com and create an example and you will get better help on this..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4m31l1 i do have some errors now

Answer (score 1):

The error is about how you're loading your javascript files. It is loading the javascript files right after loading the whole document, so when you make your jQuery calls, it doesn't recognize it and that's why you're getting those Runtime Errors.

**Solution:** In the html file, move the following lines to the beggining and switch the order between them, you need to load jQuery first because the carousel depends of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
```

:)

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Can you check the console?

Comment: Thats the problem... the carousel works as a stand alone but when iimplement it in my website its not showing

Comment: I don't get it, it should work anyway. So didn't the zip I sent you in the link work for you? Do you get any error message in the Browser's javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

You can't initiate the carousel **before** you load the scripts and jquery needs to load first. Also your CSS needs to be in the head not the body of the html.

put the css in the head:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Load the scripts as follows. They can be in the head but better at the end of the html.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>            
   <script type="text/javascript">
                $(window).load(function() {
                    $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                        responsiveBreakpoints: {
                            portrait: {
                                changePoint:480,
                                visibleItems: 1
                            },
                            landscape: {
                                changePoint:640,
                                visibleItems: 2
                            },
                            tablet: {
                                changePoint:768,
                                visibleItems: 3
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```